# C++ assign dereference pointer object to a variable and use that

Tags: c++

Hea everyone!

First of all, I am a completely new to C++ coming from a basic C background so it might be a little weird why I ask this.

The use scenario is that I want to change a map inside a different function by passing the map as a pointer to that function. Because I was reusing someone else's code, it was easier to assign the dereference to a variable instead of changing all of the references. This results in a similar case as this:

```
using namespace std;
typedef map<long, double> tl_t;

void fillmap(tl_t* m_p) {
    tl_t m = *m_p;
    m.insert(pair<long, double>(4, 3.0));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    tl_t m;

    cout << "Size: " << m.size() << "\n";
    fillmap(&m);
    cout << "Size: " << m.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The funny thing is that now both Size: strings return 0 and the original map m in the main function does not seem to be changed. This, however, works:

```
using namespace std;
typedef map<long, double> tl_t;

void fillmap(tl_t* m) {
    (*m).insert(pair<long, double>(4, 3.0));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    tl_t m;

    cout << "Size: " << m.size() << "\n";
    fillmap(&m);
    cout << "Size: " << m.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell, these 2 cases should be working the same as both the reference of m in the main and fillmap function reference the same object. Of course the two m variables reside somewhere differently but should be referencing the same object.

As I am writing this, one thing that might be the problem is that variable m in main IS the map object while the variable m in fillmap TRIES to be the map object but can't because dereferencing the m_p pointer and assigning it to that last m doesn't actually make the last m a reference to the same object but actually copies it. Am I on the right track here?

And yes, I do know in normal use cases you should use a parameter reference in a similar situation, but this bugged the hell out of me :P.

Hopefully someone can enlighten me!

Comment: _" but this bugged the hell out of me :P."_ Could you please elaborate about this. Indeed one would use a parameter passed by reference for this case. No need for pointers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Passing pointer is not so bad. For example I try to never use non-const references in parameters. I prefer pointers when I need to change something I pass to the function inside of it. The reason for it is that when you use non-const references as parameters, and you look at the code, you cannot simply say if `foo(a, b)` will modify `a` or `b`

Comment: Both your examples work exactly the way they would in C. (This is not a coincidence.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It bugged the hell out of me that I could not get the above example to work as I thought it should have worked :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you have to add & to explicitly say that variable is reference.

In your example:

`tl_t& m = *m_p;`

should help.

If you use just "tl_t" you create local copy of the object which is destroyed once you leave fillmap function.

Example:

```
struct X {
  int a,b;
}
```

Now types:

- X  - place in memory containing both a and b value.
- X& - place in memory containing reference (const pointer) to the X.
- X* - place in memory containing pointer to the X.

In both X and X& you can access fields of class using dot (xobject.a, xobject.b) but these are not same types.

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand the difference, stupid I couldn't get to it myself xD

Answer (score 1):

It is because that

```
tl_t m = *m_p;
```

`m` will be construct by call the copy constructor, the copy process is by value. You just insert the `pair<long, double>(4, 3.0)` into m, not m_p
However,

```
(*m).insert(pair<long, double>(4, 3.0))
```

*m is the object you passed in by pointer, so, the `pair<long, double>(4, 3.0)` is inserted to *m itself.